# Are all copulas lexical verbs?

Tags: verbs, copula

Normally, copulas hold a subject complement (or a predicate in any case). Example.

```
The sky became clear.
I am ill.
```

But what is in the definition of a lexical verb that makes copulas lexical verbs?

---

As the comments point out, I ought to be more specific.

I have recently read an article of French linguist Pollock.

> Pollock, Jean-Yves. 1989. Verb movement, UG, and the structure of IP.
>   Linguistic Inquiry 20, 365-424.

He claims that the differences between English and French with respect to syntax of sentence negation, questions, adverbs, floating quantifiers and “quantification at a distance” are correlated. He proves this in various ways. One thing that bothers me, though, is that he seems to contrast copulae and auxiliaries, but in such a strange way I have never heard of before.

Consider the following examples (from Pollock, aforementioned).

**French** infinitives:

`1.` *être* (to be) and *avoir* (to have)

- Ne pas être heureux est une condition pour écrire des romans.
- *Ne* to not be happy is a prerequisite for writing novels.
- N'être pas heureux est une condition pour écrire des romans.
- '*Ne* to be not happy ...'

As you can see, the negation in French can be in front or after the verb (a copula). More correctly, it is the verb that moves to Infl - in front of the negation - or not. Verb Movement is possible, but not obligatory in this case.

Then Pollock continues by saying "Let us now consider lexical verbs. The situation here contrasts sharply with the paradigm [in the previous examples]."

`2.` Lexical verbs

- Ne pas sembler heureux est une condition pour écrire des romans.
- '*Ne* not seem happy is a prerequisite for writing novels.'
- *Ne sembler pas heureux est une condition pour écrire des romans.
- '*Ne* to seem not happy ...'

(***** meaning "not considered standard language" or simply not possible)

This tendency in infinitives "sort-of" aligns with **English** tensed clauses.

- He is not happy.
- *He seems not happy.
- He was not arredsted.
- *He got not arrested.

"It appears that although Verb Movement can apply to auxiliaries and lexical *avoir*, it cannot apply to lexical verbs in infinitives in French."

Without going further into detail, it struck me that Pollock seems to make a distinction between *to be* (and French *être*) - which seems to be an auxiliary, according to his theory - and *to seem* (and French sembler) as a lexical verb. Even though, my gut tells me that *être* in `1.` and in *He is not happy* is as good a copula as *sembler* or **He seems not happy.*.

Comment: Are you only asking about English? The current sole answer seems to deal with the various functions of the English copula, but there could be even greater variety in other languages. I would suggest fleshing out your question a bit. Generally there should be an equivalent amount of effort put into question and answer and so far the answer show more effort and the question shows less focus. I'm very interested in this topic you've brought up by the way, so I'm not just nitpicking. (-:

Comment: @hippietrail You are right. I added more information. Please see my edit.

Comment: I've edited my answer to reply to your edit: some people only consider *be* to be a true copula.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**[Edit:** Some people consider only *be/être* a copula; verbs like *seem/sembler, become/devenir*, etc. they consider lexical verbs. I believe their reason is that they consider only *be* devoid of any non-grammatical function, whereas *seem* also means "affect the perception of others", and *become* "change".

I have only ever encountered this narrow sense in certain branches formal linguistics of the Anglo-Saxon school, not in other disciplines or places, but it has some merit, and perhaps it is more widespread than I know. It is something to take into account when you see someone talking about "copulae"; if only writers always had the time to define their terms... **]**

---

The idea is that **lexical verbs express more than a mere grammatical function**, while auxiliary verbs express only grammatical function, such as tense, number, or modality. Some consider copulae lexical verbs, others do not.

---

> I can't see you.

The auxiliary modal verb *can* merely adds a notion of modality and presentness to the action or state of seeing.

However, the distinction is one of convenience, not a rigid or even consistent one. What comprises a grammatical function and what lexical content is a semantic criterion, and not one that can be easily defined or tested.

> The suicide note rules out murder.

What meaning does *rules out* add? You could say it merely adds a notion of impossibility and nothing else, just like *can't*. But we normally call *rule (out)* a lexical verb.

> Brahma is swimming.

In the present continuous, *be* is commonly considered an auxiliary verb.

> Brahma was a man.
>
> This man is Brahma .

As a copula, it is sometimes considered lexical, sometimes non-lexical. What meaning does it add? It mainly establishes identity between *Brahma* and *a/this man*. It also expresses (or implies?) that *Brahma* existed.

> Brahma existed as a man.

*Existed as* mainly expresses existence, but also identity. *Exist* is commonly treated as a lexical verb. But is it all that different from *be*? Should *exist as* be considered a copula? No, because copulae must take a subject complement ([among other requirements](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/a/1676/82)), which cannot be introduced by *as* in this way.

> Brahma was in love with Sita.
>
> Brahma felt love for Sita.

Here *be* assigns an attribute/property to the subject in the form of a prepositional phrase, the state of being in love. But *feel* can do the same thing by means of a noun, although it is limited to feelings, unlike *be*.

---

So whether or not you find existence and identity (copula + noun) or existence and attribute/property (copula + adjectival phrase) a mere grammatical function should determine whether or not you call copulae lexical verbs. It is a choice.

Comment: If it is possible, could you add a source that defines *to be* as non-lexical verb (in a non-auxiliary case)? It might shed more light on the issue as well. Your answer is great though, +1. Will wait for some mare answers, if any.

Comment: @Bram: Three uses of *be* are often distinguished: existential (*there is a man*), copula (*he was a man*), and non-copular auxiliary (*he was dancing*). Existential *be* is usually considered lexical by everyone; only copular *be* is dubious. A random example of an author who considers the copula *be* to be a function word, not a content word: http://books.google.nl/books?id=oZ03AAAAIAAJ&pg=PA189&lpg=PA189&dq=copula+%22function+word%22&source=bl&ots=oJJcZgxOVq&sig=3FmyQzOzb0WQfQGrxHiXQdGzvzo&hl=en&sa=X&ei=x9JjUs_8IKPX0QWhp4CgDQ&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=copula%20%22function%20word%22&f=false

Comment: The vast majority of formal semanticists treat copula *be* as semantically vacuous (or simply as an identity function). The reason is that a predicate such as [a man] is of type <e,t> (a function from entities to truth-values). This means that the predicate can compose directly with a subject of type e without mediation by the copula. The one exception to this is equatives, where both subject and object are of type e, e.g. *Hesperus is Phosphorous*. In this instance, we have to assign *be* a contentful denotation.

Comment: I'm adding this comment because i want to clarify what the grounds are for classifying a verb as *lexical* rather than *functional*. @Cerberus, you claim that the copula expresses existence and identity in your answer, but it's problematic to make such a claim without an articulated semantic theory. Under an articulated theory, the copula generally turns out to be semantically vacuous.

Comment: @PEl: I don't know what you mean by "articulate", but, as I said in my answer, you need to involve semantics in order to make a distinction between function words and content words, and there is no real clear-cut line. Do you disagree? I don't understand why you think a distinction between function and content word is at all exact enough to prove in fringe cases like this, or why it would be at all meaningful to do so. I'm interested in your reasons. *"This means that the predicate can compose directly with a subject of type e without mediation by the copula."* Not sure what you mean by this.

Comment: @Cerberus: I wouldn't say they were considered lexical by everyone; the _be_ of _There_-Insertion is clearly an auxiliary verb that's part of the construction. Indeed, _There's_ is becoming frozen with plural subjects: _There's a lotta people out there_. The progressive _be_, the passive _be_, and the predicate noun/adjective _be_ are all clearly auxiliaries. What meaning is contributed by the progressive, for instance, is not contributed by _be_, but by the construction of which _be_ is part {form of _be_ + _-ing_ form of next verb}.

Comment: @cerberus by "articulate" i suppose i mean delineating which atomic units of an expression are contributing what to its meaning. For example, i would deny that the copular expresses that the subject 'Brahma' exists, on the grounds that using the term 'Brahma' presupposes that 'Brahma' exists in pretty much every construction 'Brahma' occurs in, e.g. 'Brahma likes to drink milk'. From this, it seems sensible to conclude that the proper name itself is the locus of the *existence* component of meaning.

Comment: @cerberus *"This means that the predicate can compose directly with a subject of type e without mediation by the copula."* - by this, i mean that in formal semantics, the predicate is treated as a function from individuals to truth values. The subject is an individual, therefore the subject provides the sole argument for the function denoted by a predicate. From the perspective of a semanticist, it doesn't actually matter whether the copula is there or not. Indeed, many languages (like Russian) have a null copula.

Comment: @jlawler: All right, perhaps that was not among least controversial of instances of existential *be*. What do you think is a good example of existential be? Or do you disagree that existential *be* is widely acknowledged as a "content" verb"?

Comment: @PElliott: You could say that, and I understand the argument, but then can we still say the lexical meaning of the verb *exist* is "exist", without contradiction? Conversely, how about existential *be*, as in *in the courtyard were two wells*? Should that still have a lexical meaning? But I think I agree the implication of existence is in the sentence *Brahma was a man* as a whole rather than in *be* (and rather than in *Brahma*). To what conclusion does that lead us? I guess to the conclusion that content v. function is not a distinction that is meaningful or useful in fringe cases.

Comment: @Cerberus Au contraire, i think that the implication of existence is in *Brahma* (the word, not the deity!). I think that if we apply the meaning criterion to *be* we end up having to conclude that there are lots of different *be*s, some are content words, and some are function words. Maybe not the most satisfying solution...

Comment: @PElliott: Okay, but I'm not sure whether the finer details of what constitutes a lexical word fall under the purview of formal semantics? Predicate logic and formal semantics rather seem to make certain choices as to what they convert into the building blocks of their formulae, recognising that those choice are to some degree arbitrary, but working with what they have. And that makes sense. At least that is my impression.

Comment: @PElliott: Why do you think the implication of existence in in *Brahma* and not in the whole sentence? How can you then explain why there is no implication of his existence in *does Brahma exist?*, or *Brahma does not exist*...? I rather think his existence has to do with pragmatics at the sentence level.

Comment: @cerberus Yeah...statements of existence are problematic. The reason i want to say the locus of existence is in *Brahma* is because of the principle of compositionality - the meaning of a construction should be a function of the meanings of its parts. There are good conceptual reasons not to attribute meanings to whole constructions. I'm not sure how to explain the statements of existence though, it's an interesting problem.

Comment: @PElliott: Ah, well, that principle is exactly the basket I wouldn't put all my eggs in in language; that is, it applies to certain phenomena, but not to others, and rarely or never to the final human interpretation of language. Context is almost always important, for example. Trying to analyse an utterance according to the metaphor of building blocks is useful, but not complete; a metaphor like currents in a river, or, e.g., a landscape the result of overlapping impact craters, can lead to other pieces of the puzzle in many cases.

Comment: @Cerberus: my position is that _be_ is totally bleached of semantics and is always and only an auxiliary in English. This is true **only** of _be_, btw; it's exceptional. _Have_ does have a lexical (though pretty vague) sense of 'possess'.

Comment: @jlawler: Okay, noted. I personally consider the whole distinction between meaning and function useful, but less practical or sustainable in more involved contexts. It's more like a handy rule of thumb, not something fundamental. E.g., I'm not sure tense or number or modality expresses less "meaning" as opposed to "function" to me than the word *relation* or *different* or *include*. I see levels but not black and white.

Comment: @Cerberus: Tense, modality, number, and other grammatical functions are more predictable (logically and grammatically speaking) but less precise in their semantics. Generally they are more subject to idiomatization and heavy (but often extremely idiosyncratic) pragmatic interpretations. I agree that the distinction is useful, but not terribly important, and that it's a matter of gradation -- some words are more bleached than others. But _be_ is at the end point of that scale; it's got no color left at all.

Comment: @jlawler Do note British lexical *have* that has a more distinct and/or prominent meaning than it has in other varieties of English. You can say, for instance, *Have you any money?* which clearly marks the verb and which is not vague.

Comment: Yes, exactly. The syntactic affordances are different for _have_; it hasn't bleached everything away -- though 'possess' **is** an awfully generic meaning, bleachable to a noun case or an existential particle in some languages -- and there is still variable syntax. _Be_, on the other hand, is totally predictable in syntax; everything's fixed.